# Cognito/Lambda: validation in PreSignUp_SignUp

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm building a very small app on Amplify with Cognito. In sign-up form I have an extra attribute called "activation_key" which is like a beta token. I would like to validate this key and if it's wrong, I need to return an error.

When looking at the documentation, for an operation called "Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger" I see the description "Custom validation to accept or deny the sign-up request". Sounds perfect. But the actual documentation of this Trigger - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html, does not include any example of such validation at the time of writing this.

I discovered that when I return from lambda callback(new Error('custom message')) it does almost what I need. It returns a message "PreSignUp failed with error ${myCustomErrorMessage}". It makes me think that maybe there is a better way and I'm just doing something wrong.

**What is the proper way of returning validation error from Lambda Cognito PreSignUp_SignUp hook?**

Possible workarounds:

- Stop using Amplify UI elements (ReactJS) and just do it in a custom way, intercept error, and remove the string "PreSignUp failed with error" before displaying error
- Let anyone sign up but ask for activation_key as the next step, outside of Cognito flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use-case does not sound plausible with the `PreSignUp` Lambda Trigger, and I would instead state that handling the activation_key outside of Cognito's flow would be a better option.

Another way(a recommended way) to achieve this use-case would be to use the `CUSTOM_AUTH` Authentication flow. 
In the `DefineAuthChallenge` Lambda Trigger in the `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow, you could set the parameters that would be needed during the Cognito Authentication flow(Passwords, OTPs, CAPTCHAs, etc). To get a better understanding of the `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow, I would recommend you to go through this [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow).

Comment: I think the `CUSTOM_AUTH` is only for signing-in and not signing-up. It would be really nice to have the same thing for signing-up... In the meantime I guess you either deal with the inability to have custom error types or you wrap the Cognito call with API GW + Lambda to do your custom check before creating the account.